# Biblatex: changing the journal abbreviations

Tags: biblatex

I'm quite happy with the changes to my bibliography so far. Except for one thing I'm struggling with.

I want to change the abbreviations for the volume and number of the `@article` to "Vol." and "No.", but I have to set the language to `ngerman`.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=27.5mm,right=16mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{BA.bib}
@online{polymer2020,
  title = {Polymer},
  author = {{N. N.}},
  journaltitle = {Wikipedia},
  url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer},
  urldate = {2020-02-16},
  langid = {german}
}

@thesis{kaddar2010,
  title = {Die generative Fertigung mittels Laser-Sintern: Scanstrategien, Einfl\"usse verschiedener Prozessparameter auf die mechanischen und optischen Eigenschaften beim LS von Thermoplasten und deren  Nachbearbeitungsm\"oglichkeiten},
  author = {Kaddar, Wesam},
  date = {2010},
  institution = {{Universit\"at Duisburg-Essen}},
  location = {{Duisburg}},
  langid = {german},
  type = {Dissertation}
}

@incollection{hans2020,
  title = {Ein {{Qualit\"atsicherungskonzept}}},
  booktitle = {Additive {{Fertigung}} von {{Bauteilen}}},
  author = {Hans, Peter and Werner, Meier},
  editor = {Furman, Bernd and Eder, Max},
  date = {2020},
  publisher = {{Springer}},
  location = {{Berlin}}
}

@article{drummer2010,
  title = {Untersuchung der Materialalterung bei pulverbasierten Schichtbauverfahren},
  author = {Drummer, Dietmar and K\"uhnlein, Florian and Rietzel, Dom and H\"udler, Gerrit},
  date = {2010},
  journaltitle = {RTejournal - Forum f\"ur Rapid Technologie},
  volume = {7},
  langid = {german},
  number = {1}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric, sorting=nyt, autocite=inline, isbn=false, dashed=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{BA.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings]{series}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat*[online]{title}{\textit{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\textit{#1}\addperiod}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\textit{#1}\addperiod}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
\printunit{\addperiod\space}%
\printlist{location}%
\iflistundef{publisher}
{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
{\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
\printlist{publisher}%
\setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
\usebibmacro{date}%
\newunit}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{online}
{\printtext[parens]{\usebibmacro{date}}}
{\usebibmacro{date}}
{}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{online}
{\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
{\setunit{\addperiod\space}\newblock
\usebibmacro{url+urldate}}
{}{}


\begin{document}

\autocite{polymer2020} \autocite{hans2020} \autocite{kaddar2010} \autocite{drummer2010}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want English abbreviations for journal and number in a German document, you can redefine the bibstrings.

(In the MWE I removed everything that was not essential for the question, so that it is easier to spot what needs to be done: You only need the `\DefineBibliographyStrings` block.)

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  jourvol = {vol\adddot},
  number  = {no\adddot},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{drummer2010,
  title        = {Untersuchung der Materialalterung bei pulverbasierten Schichtbauverfahren},
  author       = {Drummer, Dietmar and Kühnlein, Florian and Rietzel, Dom and Hüdler, Gerrit},
  date         = {2010},
  journaltitle = {RTejournal - Forum für Rapid Technologie},
  volume       = {7},
  langid       = {ngerman},
  number       = {1}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{drummer2010}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: D. Drummer, F. Kühnlein, D. Rietzel und G. Hüdler, “Untersuchung der Materialalterung bei pulverbasierten Schichtbauverfahren,” RTejournal - Forum für Rapid Technologie, vol. 7, no. 1, 2010.]